# How to set different background color for each repeated column of RadioButtonList

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, css, radiobuttonlist

I set 3 repeated columns, I want to use different background color for each repeated column, please share if you have any idea about how I can achieve this.

Below is my `RadioButtonList` code

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTimeSlot" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatLayout="Table" AutoPostBack="False" CellPadding="10" CellSpacing="2" Font-Bold="False"></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

The item list is loading from Database on another event.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child)(>=IE9):

```
#rblTimeSlot tr:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color:aqua;
}
```

Or jquery:

```
$("#rblTimeSlot tr:even").css("background-color","aqua");
```

If you want to do the same for columns, use this slightly changed css:

```
#rblTimeSlot tr > td:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color:aqua;
}
```

Or jquery:

```
$("#rblTimeSlot tr>td:even").css("background-color","aqua");
```

Comment: It works but for rows only How can I make it for columns

Comment: Works Great, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can write the code in your XX.aspx.cx file like this:

```
string[] color = { "red", "yellow","blue" };
for (int i = 0; i < rblTimeSlot.Items.Count; i++)
{
     int j = i % color.lenght;
     rblTimeSlot.Items[i].Attributes.Add("style", "color: " + color[j]+ ";");

}
```

Comment: There is no specific number of timeslots so I need to specify long array of colors, but answer is useful one may use this somewhere else :)